# Grab random variable from variable list

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to grab a random variable of a list of variables.

```
$variable1 = 'Random1'; $variable2 = 'Random2'; $variable3 = 'Random3';
```

How would i grab a random variable?

Comment: Use an array and then you use PHP's built in functions to get a random value.

Comment: @SevnDK do you need more help? Is none of the answers good enough?

Comment: @Andreas answers are good enough, reporting to get closed now!

Comment: @SevnDK Then mark one of the answers as accepted so that others know this question is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your current setup you can do like this:

```
$x=rand(1,3);
echo ${"variable" .$x};
```

Or slightly shorter code:

```
echo ${"variable" .rand(1,3)};
```

Working example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f633c101d5e8a75137e6daf16d2b788587326743

Comment: Just to note in case someone doesnt understand this, this only works if all the variables have the same names and just different numbers in the variables. So if one of the variables would be called: `$variablee`, it wont work.

Comment: That is true. But He didn't say that in the question so in my opinion it does not excist :-)

Comment: I'm not saying this is not the solution. This is definitely doing what OP wants it to do.

Comment: I was joking. I know of the issue but OP has to say if it is an issue. I believe he can keep lots of code with this setup but array is probably smarter for the future

Comment: @Andreas, so "variable"
Is my variable name?

Comment: That was what you wrote?... Here have a look at this working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f633c101d5e8a75137e6daf16d2b788587326743

Comment: @SevnDK, Just to make it clear the first `$`starts the variable name then there is curlybrackets `{` which means "implode" everything in here. And the thing I'm imploding is string "variable" as the names of your variables in question, and a random number which is the number you had in your `$variable1`

Comment: @SevnDK another example would be `echo ${"Sevn"."DK"};`will echo a variable called `$SevnDK`

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in an array and then do something like this:

```
$array=array('Random1','Random2','Random3');
```

this will have the keys: 0,1 and 2.

So you could generate a random number with min:0 and max:2 like this:

```
rand(0,2);
```

And then use that as index for the array:

```
echo $array[rand(0,2)];
```

This will output a random value.

Comment: i can't do that since it's like this
`$account = new \PSN\Auth\Auth("a", "1");
$account2 = new \PSN\Auth\Auth("b", "2");
$account3 = new \PSN\Auth\Auth("c", "3");
$account4 = new \PSN\Auth\Auth("d", "4");
$account5 = new \PSN\Auth\Auth("e", "5");`

Comment: yeah sorry i edited the comment accidentally hit the enter button!

Comment: @SevnDK Sorry what? So $variable1 in the example is in real, $account and $variable2 is $account2?

Comment: yeah, i didn't want to include the PSN Auth stuff.

Comment: @SevnDK You could still put the values of those variables in an array.

Comment: To allow this to scale I would recommend the following: `echo $array[rand(0, count($array)-1)];` This way it doesn't matter how many items the array has. The *max* argument in the `rand(min, max)` function will always incorporate *all* of the array values.